# Как подключиться к камере web-пользователя?

Tags: python, opencv, web-camera

Необходимо получить несколько изображений с камеры пользователя сайта. Не знаю как подключиться к камере web-пользователя, используя python и opencv.
Что нужно передать в качестве параметра методу VideoCapture?

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Comment: Камера подключена к компу, на котором скрипт выполняется? Или камера удаленная и доступ к ней нужен по сети? Или вы, судя по предыдущим вопросам, пытаетесь получить изображение с камеры пользователя сайта? Обрисуйте задачу, не заставляйте людей гадать что вы хотите сделать :)

Comment: @gil9red Удалённая камера пользователя веб-сайта.

Comment: @gil9red Хочу получить несколько изображений с камеры пользователя сайта.

Comment: А при чём тут python? У всех ваших пользователей ваш же браузер написанный на python?

Comment: @vp_arth в дальнейшем посредством python происходит обработка данных изображений. Систему распознавание лиц необходимо сделать.

Comment: Вы понимаете, на каком CPU крутится ваш Python, а на каком браузер пользователя с камерой? Без javascript вам не обойтись.

Comment: `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` захватывает изображение с камеры подключенной на машине, где скрипт выполняется. А это там где вебсервер запущен, т.е. это не ваш вариант. Для получения кадров вебкамеры юзера нужен вебсервер и js (на стороне клиента), с сайта кадры с камеры будут передаваться как картинки, вы их получаете приводите в формат который понимает детектор (по-моему, там нужен numpy), что-то с ними делаете и, например, отправляете на страницу юзера, например, с найденными объектами